# C# Enum in a C++ Library

Tags: c#, c++, enums, com

I'm having issues using a `public enum` defined in C# within a C++ Interface. The .NET project is exposed to COM to be used within C++ and VB legacy software.

C# Code:

```
namespace ACME.XXX.XXX.XXX.Interfaces.Object
{
   [Guid(".....")]
   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   public interface TestInterface
   {
       void Stub();
   }

   [ComVisible(true)]
   public enum TestEnum
   {
        a = 1,
        b = 2
   }
}
```

C++ Code:

**Edit:** In the idl for the project I imported the tlb. (`importlib("\..\ACME.XXX.XXX.XXX.Interfaces.tlb")`)

```
interface ITestObject : IDispatch
{
  [id(1), helpstring("one")]
  HRESULT MethodOne([in] TestInterface *a);

  [id(2), helpstring("two")]     
  HRESULT MethodTwo([in] TestEnum a);
}
```

In `MethodTwo`, I keep getting errors stating

> Excepting Type Specification near TestEnum

I'm assuming there's something I'm not doing correctly. `MethodOne` seems to be finding the reference correctly.

**Is there some magic to referencing .NET enum object in C++ interface?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are a fairly quirky, the type library that you got from your C# project does not have a typedef for `TestEnum`.  You can write it like this instead:

```
  [id(2), helpstring("two")]     
  HRESULT MethodTwo([in] enum TestEnum a);
```

Note the added `enum` keyword.  Or you can declare your own typedef if you use the identifier in multiple places or need it in your C++ code, put it before your interface declaration:

```
  typedef enum TestEnum TestEnum;
```

You probably prefer the latter.